# Fat Server + Thin Rich Client in .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I am working out the nitty gritty of a potential server / many-client project and it's in a realm I haven't been before. *Disregarding the scale of the project for a moment and assuming this ever goes ahead....*

My current idea is that the server should be a fat server with a thin rich client on each workstation, built in C# .NET and probably using WinForms for the user interface, and distributed via ClickOnce for easy and compliant software updating.

`Database <-> Server (business logic) <-> Rich Thin Client`

Instead of a fat client:

`Database <-> Client`

I am looking into WCF for the server. Is this advisable for a client-server architecture with the following usage case?

- Anywhere between 10 and 100 receptionists and practitioners using the client (company growth would increase this)
- Windows 7 and up being primary workstation operating system
- Minimal data traffic desirable
- Potential for large data to be stored alongside the database in some manner (patient images, video and such)

Is it wise for the server to be performing business logic as much as possible and only sending information and results and doing the basics on the client (validation etc)? It seems logical to me.

Does anyone have some good information on beginning such a big project?

I believe the current software being used is actually a fat client with a direct MSSQL connection.

Not only this, it is also non-distributed and each clinic has it's own separate database causing many problems with data integrity and collation for reporting and such.

Comment: You might be able to get more help on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, since it's more tailored for questions such as this.

Comment: Did you give web applications a thought?

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid plan for your architecture. WCF will do fine. If you need a tutorial on authentication sharing between the web application that authenticates users and the ClickOnce module run from within the application, I wrote one once:

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2008/02/clickonce-webservice-and-shared-forms.html

This was written years ago and while I show how to share authentication between the ClickOnce and ASMX web service, sometime later I wrote another tutorial on sharing the authentication between a Silverlight module and a WCF service.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2010/04/aspnet-forms-authentication-sharing-for.html

Combining these two will give you ClickOnce + WCF authentication sharing.